# pass the value attribute into (click) attribute within HTML tag

Tags: angularjs, node.js, typescript

I have the following HTML template:

```
<form #topping (change)="updateTopping(topping)">
    <span *ngFor= "let top of toppingOptions">
        {{top.name}} 
        {{top.price.toFixed(2)}}
        <button type="button" value="{{top.name}}-add" (click)="addTopping({{top.name}})">+</button>
        <button type="button" value="{{top.name}}-minus" (click)="minusTopping({{top.name}})">-</button>
        <br>
    </span>    
</form>
```

As you can probably tell the error occurs in the Button tag. I want to pass "top.name" into addTopping() and minusTopping(), but don't know the correct way of doing so.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove the curly brackets and pass the parameter to `(click)` function

```
 <button type="button" value="{{top.name}}-add" (click)="addTopping(top.name)">+</button>
```

Comment: Thank you! Say if I wanted to pass in the actual value attribute, how would I do that? So if value="Bacon-add", how would i pass the value attribute directly into my (click)="addTopping(valueAttribute)" parameter?

Comment: try this `(click)="addTopping(top.name + '-add')">`

Comment: Thank you, I'm new to typescript. I just realized how dumb of a question that was..

Comment: hehe don't beat yourself up. :D